# How to get the last before character between two characters from string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, range

I need to get the last before character between two characters from string how to do it using javascript. I tried a lot and searched in google I didnt find any answer.

for my example string output is

```
A26261990L|B26261992S|
```

by using the below logic I could able to get the `26261990L` this output as per my need.

```
str.split('A').pop().split('|')[0]
```

I need to fetch "L" and based on two characters "A", "|". as well as "s" based on two characters "B", "|" etc...

How to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Can you clarify your input and output? It's not clear at the moment.

Comment: this my string output A26261990L|B26261992S| ... if use between "A", "|". I should get the response "L" the same way for "B", "|" I should get the response "S"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "character" you mean letter, then here is a piece of logic that might help you. I'm finding a start and end index of the characters that are passed in, and if it's possible to search, then iterate from end index backwards.

Also, notice `str.indexOf(end, startIdx)`. It checks for the index of the end character *after* the index of the start character.

```js
function between(str, start, end) {
  const startIdx = str.indexOf(start);
  // Find end index after start index
  const endIdx = str.indexOf(end, startIdx);
  
  if (startIdx === -1 || endIdx === -1 || startIdx >= endIdx) {
    // Not specified in the question
    return "Not found";
  }
  
  for (let i = endIdx - 1; i > startIdx; i--) {
    if (str[i] >= "A" && str[i] <= "Z") {
      return str[i];
    }
  }
  
  // Not specified in the question
  return "Not found";
}

const str = "A26261990L|B26261992S|";

console.log(between(str, "A", "|"));
console.log(between(str, "B", "|"));
console.log(between(str, "C", "|"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
var str = "A26261990L|B26261992S|";
var splitted = str.split("|");
var item1 = splitted[0];
var item2 = splitted[1];
console.log(item1.charAt(item1.length-1));
console.log(item2.charAt(item2.length-1));
```

Which fetches the "L" and the "S" in the string

Comment: my string will have many characters based on two characters only i need to find the last before character .  i should check the condition like this  in between "A", "|". or in between "B", "|" and so on..

Comment: @rajivks2 I don't understand what you mean.